# Making scrollRectToVisible work with a panel laid out with GroupLayout

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane

A rather minimal example: This lays out a `JLabel` in a `JPanel`, stuffs the `JPanel` into a `JScrollPane`, and sticks that in a `JFrame`. I then *want* the pane to scroll so as to make the `JLabel` visible, but it does not do so. I've tried calling `scrollRectToVisible` on the label and the panel, with no luck, messed around with viewports, with no luck, tried setting scrollbar values manually, with no luck. Clearly I'm doing something stupid, but I can't see what.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SillyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(panel);
                panel.setLayout(layout);
                GroupLayout.SequentialGroup seq = layout
                        .createSequentialGroup();
                GroupLayout.ParallelGroup par = layout.createParallelGroup();
                JLabel fish = new JLabel("fish");
                seq.addGap(3000);
                seq.addComponent(fish);
                par.addComponent(fish);
                par.addGap(200);
                layout.setHorizontalGroup(par);
                layout.setVerticalGroup(seq);
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("whatever this is about");
                frame.add(scrollPane);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                fish.scrollRectToVisible(fish.getBounds());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code works fine for me using JDK7 on Windows7.

If you have an issue on a different version then you can try:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        fish.scrollRectToVisible(fish.getBounds());
    }
});
```

This just makes sure the scrollRectToVisible() is added to the end of the EDT so it should be processed after all the initial logic to display the frame has occurred.

Comment: In the code I gave in the question, *everything* runs in the EDT, so I don't see how that could be the problem. Adding a separate `Runnable` to do the scrolling seems *much* more complicated, because `fish` would have to be passed from the first to the second somehow.

Comment: @dfeuer, I know the code is executing on the EDT. But some methods also invoke SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to place code on the end of the EDT, which means your scrollRectToVisible() may in fact be executing before it should. Using an invokeLater() is a common technique to make sure you code is at the end of the EDT. As I already stated the code works fine for me.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it still doesn't scroll down to make the fish visible. I seems rather unlikely that I would have stumbled into a bug in openjdk, but I suppose anything's possible.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't seem to be an openjdk bug. I switched to Sun and it's still doing the same thing.